# How to update blueimp jquery file upload to use Bootstrap 4+

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp, bootstrap-4

Welcomed dear reader!

It seems Bootstrap 4 does not use the CSS class .in{...} any more.

This influences blueimp jquery file upload in the way that the list of files to be uploaded will not be shown after pressing the Add files button.

Do I do anything wrong? - Or can this class be added to the blueimp jquery file upload framwork/app?...

Best wishes!

Answer (score 16):

Just add this to your stylesheet

```
.fade.in {
    opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: Is there another option?

Answer (score 4):

I may be a little late but I made it work by adding `show` after `fade` to the `<tr>` tags.

```
<tr class="template-download fade show">
```

and

```
<tr class="template-upload fade show">
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery.fileupload-ui.js

find the line

```js
      showElementClass: 'in',
```

change to

```js
      showElementClass: 'show',
```